# Our developer created our Facebook App and is no longer with the company. How do we change the admin?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

How do you change the admin for a Facebook App when the admin developer left the company and didn't delegate access?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an administration issue, not a programming one.

Answer (score 2):

Only the administrator of the app can add another admin.

So, only your developer has the power to delegate the rights to you and no one.

If there are not many users in your app, I would suggest you to a create new app and change the app credentials in the code. But of-course, the authentication step will be repeated for the existing users.

Answer (score 1):

The first step that I would take is check developers.facebook.com and see if he did in face delegate access.

When you go their go to apps (upper menu on the screen), and then check to see if your app shows in that list. If it does click on it and then go to roles thats on the sub-menu on the left hand side. If you are a administrator then you can remove him.

If the namespace of your app isn't important, such you are accessing the api from a website then you can create a new app and just use that one. The down side here is that all your users's access tokens would be invalid. They also might wonder why they see two simular looking apps that they have granted permission to.

Another thought is that you could ask your question in this group, as I don't have a ton of experience, but I really doubt that their will be anything you can do as he is the administrator. (basically he owns it)